# Making Images Stay to The Left Of The Article

Tags: html, css, image

I want my article to surround my image like in newspaper articles.
CSS:

```
img {position:absolute;left:0;width:40%;}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Use `float : left;` and margin as desired.

Comment: Sorry another user who uses the same computer posted this and was not logged out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't make position absolute instead float img to left or right...

```
img { float: left; margin: desired px; }
```

Comment: I'm sorry another user of my computer posted this but for some reason it posted on mine? Or they forgot to log out...